# Does Docker's mount technology - v mean that there are two identical data files in Linux at the same time?

Tags: docker

In Docker technology, the mount volume can map the directory in the container and the directory of the host computer to achieve the container data persistence in the host computer. Is it understandable that a data in the container is a space for the expansion of a Linux host computer, and the mounted host computer directory and the container data are the same, and also occupy a space for Linux? If there is only one file, when the container is running, will it take up two spaces of the machine, one on the host and the other in the container?

Comment: The filesystem driver in docker allows the running container to *"see"* and use some space that exists on the host.

Comment: "Bind mounts" turn out to be a generic Unix concept that's not specific to Docker.  There is literally only one copy of the files even though they're visible in both the host and container filesystems.

Answer (score 1):

From https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/ :

In addition, volumes are often a better choice than persisting data in a container’s writable layer, **because a volume does not increase the size of the containers using it**, and the volume’s contents exist outside the lifecycle of a given container.